# Can I import the a Hyper-V VM version 9.0 to a machine where the version is 8.0?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, import

On one machine I have **Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB** installed. On the other one it's **Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019**. What I need to do is export my Hyper-V VM version 9.0 from **Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC 2019** and then import it to **Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB** where the highest supported version is 8.0. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a new VM on the computer with Hyper-V version 8.0.

Then you may add to it the virtual Hard drive (VHDX) from the
VM on Hyper-V version 9.0.

Comment: What about all the Snapshots I have? So I don't have to do the import? Also I have one (VHDX)-file and many (AVHDX)-files. Do I have to do anything with them as well?